# Statistical methods for analyzing symptoms correlation with nutrients

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I am working on a web based project that will track a person's symptoms and drugs and nutrients they intake. For example thyroid patients symptoms of fatigue vs the dose of thyroid and also how much selenium, iodine, vitamin A, protein, etc they get from food or supplements.

I've added a basic set of descriptive statistics functions, linear regression functions, but am not sure these are appropriate for this type of analysis. Most biological systems are very complex and multiple factors may influence a symptom. The math/statistics books I've skimmed seem to talk about science experiments where one variable is isolated which is not the case here. Could anybody recommend some reading materials or information that could help with this type of analysis? My background is in biology and programming, not statistics.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Could you explain some more about why you're doing this.  Are you looking at lots of different people to find a correlation between, or do you want to provide individual information back to individual people ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

You are correct in that many books look at a single variable. I might suggest searching this site for Multivariate analysis. There is an answer [dealing with books](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2181/2591) that you may find helpful.