# Recommendations for mathematical multivariate statistics with exercises

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, references

I need a graduate level, mathematically rigorous textbook on multivariate analysis and inference to enhance myself. I've been reading the [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ElemStatLearn/) and doing the problems within, but I need a book with other focuses. Topics like famous distributions (Wishart, Wilks lambda, etc.), hypothesis testing, some theory on estimation (point, interval), and other more modern materials are welcome. I've checked [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2181/4864), but the OP there was looking for something useful for his psychological analysis, which is not exactly what I want here. Currently I have the [An Introduction to Multivariate Statistical Analysis](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471360910,descCd-tableOfContents.html), so I would also like to hear the comments about this book and its exercises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendations for study material for mathematical statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625357/recommendations-for-study-material-for-mathematical-statistics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Anderson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471360910) is probably the most mathematical of the existing textbooks, and as such is orthogonal to the material in HTF. So this could be a good fit for you. I wrote an [Amazon list](https://web.archive.org/web/20151103174119/http://www.amazon.com/lm/R3312L94GKFZD1/) on multivariate books when I was looking for one to teach both an elective doctorate course, and an applied master's course. [Mardia, Kent and Bibby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124712525) and [Rencher](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471418897) top that list, so either one could be a decent alternative if Anderson proves to be too heavy.

Comment: You write some really good book reviews.

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, if you want something still more theoretical than Anderson's book, you can go with Muirhead:  "[Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316559)". This is if you really want to enter the theory of the Wishart distribution.  A book that focuses on the mathematics behind multivariate statistics is Roger H. Farrell: "[Multivariate Calculation: Use of the Continuous Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8528-8)" which I also have found useful.

Answer (score 2):

My graduate program at UCSB taught with An Introduction to Multivariate Analysis and it is a very good book for learning the basic tools however, it is not overly theoretical or filled with too many proofs (I always felt like it was an undergrad text).  However, I do think its an excellent book in solidifying the concepts and the exercises are is very good at actually allowing you to use the methods/concepts as if you were applying them to the real world and not just deriving theory. Just my two cents.