# Linear Regression with Multiple Input and Output Variables, Matrix Invertibility Condition?

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, linear

I'm trying to work out a linear regression model where **both** inputs and outputs are multidimensional.

Suppose we have $n$ input variables, $m$ output variables and $k$ observations. Each observation can be represented as an $n+m$-vector: $(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m)$. The full set of observations can be represented with two matrices:

$X$ an $n\times k$ matrix of inputs. Each row is one input variable. Each column is one datapoint.

$Y$ an $m\times k$ matrix of outputs. Each row is one output variable. Each column is one datapoint.

The model can be summarized as $Y\approx AX+B$, where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $m$-vector (well technically, an $m$-vector copied $k$ times to form an $m\times k$ matrix). The goal is to find optimal values for $A$ and $B$.

I think the natural choice is to minimize $\sum_i \sum_j (y_{ij} - predicted(y_{ij}))^2$, i.e. the sum of squares with all output variables and all observations weighted equally. That is, $\sum_i \sum_j ((y_i-\sum_l a_{il}x_{lj})-b_i)^2$.

I worked it out and found that for any fixed $A$, the minimum occurs when $b_i=mean_j (y_{ij}) – \sum_l a_{il} mean_j (x_{lj})$.

The hard part is finding $A$. After plugging in the minimizing value of $B$, the function to be minimized is: [image], where

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

where $dx_{ij} = x_{ij} – mean_j(x_{ij}), dy_{ij}=y_{ij} – mean_j(y_{ij})$

This is a quadratic function in the entries of $A$. It attains its minimum precisely at its critical point(s). To find those, condense the $S^2_{ij}$ and $S^2_{ijj'}$ into a single $nm\times nm$ matrix:

[image]

Here we think of the pair of indices $ij$ as if it were a single index via a bijection between pairs of integers in $[1,n]\times [1,m]$ and integers in $[1,nm]$. Then minimizing values of $A$ are exactly given by solutions to the equation $S^2\vec{A}=-\frac{1}{2}S^1$, where $S^1$ is a column vector storing the $S^1_{ij}$ in the order given by that bijection and $\vec{A}$ is $A$ collapsed down to a single $nm$-length column vector via that same bijection.

$S^2$ is always positive semidefinite. If it is positive definite, then we're in the nice case of a single optimal solution $\vec{A}=(S^2)^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}S^1)$. But if not, then I suppose we might get a positive-dimensional set of optimal solutions.

So my question is: Is there a nice theorem, preferably with a clear statistical interpretation, to tell when that matrix is not invertible? And can it be derived from the formulas above? Something analogous to the one-variable case, where the least-squares line breaks down iff var(X)=0, i.e. all the datapoints have the same input value.

Note: I found many results when searching for multivariable linear regression, but the ones I found all assumed only 1 output variable; so I had to derive this more general case myself. I did find one helpful reference on multivariable quadratic functions [here](https://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/15/tm821.pdf)

Comment: I'm not certain based on your question but you might be looking for the topic called "multivariate regression". If so, then here's a link to something that looked decent at a glance. https://math.unm.edu/~james/w15-STAT576b.pdf

Comment: Hello, I looked through the link. Notational differences aside, they provide a similar formula to the 1 output variable case, but with no discussion about invertibility. So it doesn't quite answer my question. Let me try updating my question with some more detail.

Comment: This doesn't address your main question, but as mlofton says, `multivariate` refers to >1 outputs. `multiple` and `multivariable` (I prefer `multiple`) refer to >1 inputs. Unfortunately, this terminology is just poor and there is **lots** of confusion around the terms.

Comment: @mkt: I couldn't find any other useful resource on the net but here is a link for multivariate analysis textbooks. Maybe one of those has what you are looking for. It seems like your deriving your own steps for figuring out the best estimate. There should be be a closed form solution but I can't find it.  Maybe check out some of these recommendations.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/book-recommendations-for-multivariate-analysis#:~:text=Izenman%2C%20J.%20Modern%20Multivariate%20Statistical%20Techniques